# How to add legend on a line plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data like this

```
    year    catch   group
    2011    22       1
    2012    45       1
    2013    34       1
    2011    11       2
    2012    22       2
    2013    32       2
```

I would like to have the number of the group (1 and 2) to appear above the line in the plot. 
Any suggestion?

My real data has 8 groups in total with 8 lines which makes it hard to see because the lines cross one another and the colors of the legend are similar.

I tried this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(year), y=catch, group=as.factor(group), 
           col=as.factor(group)), data=df) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  xlab("year") + 
  labs(color="group")
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, distinguishing 8 different colours is very difficult. That's why your 8 groups seem to have similar colors.

What you want in this case is not a legend (which usually is an off-chart summary), but rather "annotation". 
You can directly add the groups with

```
ggplot(...) +
geom_text(aes(x=as.factor(year), y=catch, label=group)) +
...
```

and then try to tweak the position of the text with `nudge_x` and `nudge_y`. But if you wanted only 1 label per group, you would have to prepare a data frame with it:

```
labels <- df %>% group_by(group) %>% top_n(1, -year)
ggplot(...) +
geom_text(data=labels, aes(x=as.factor(year), y=catch, label=group)) +
...
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it @MrGumble